# Get google people profile API does not return birthday and gender key values

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, google-api, google-people-api

`GPPSignIn *signIn;`

In my iOS app I am setting scope as:

```
signIn.scopes = @[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
                  @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
                  @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read", 
                  @"email",
                  @"profile",
                  @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read"];
```

Also,

```
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
```

And trying to get `access_token` from Google. which I get and send to server.

Now, my server is doing this:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('app_id', 'app_secret')
access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, access_token)
profile_api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me'
response = access_token.get(profile_api_url)
google_profile_res_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Here, `google_profile_res_body` is having many properties but not birthday and gender.

Anyone have any idea? Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Rahul

Comment: update: New accounts created are not having these properties but I tested with accounts created a year and 4 years ago, google apis return both the fields, weird huh?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely the problem is that the birthday and gender is only returned if the fields have been set to have a **public** visibility. Private visibility fields won't be returned.

If you use the **Google People API** which is different than the **G+ People API**, you should be able to get the private birthday with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read` scope. Unfortunately there is no private scope for gender.

See documentation of Google People API at https://developers.google.com/people/ for more info.

Comment: I have already made the birthday and gender public in my google account settings. So, I dont think thats the issue. I guess, its because of the reason I have mentioned in the comment to my question.