# Passport js Google Ouath2 scopes

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

I have a project and this project has a login page which I use passport js google-ouath20.

I need gender, birthdate information, that's why I added new scopes on google
[image]

```
router.get(
  "/login/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: [  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read", "profile", "email" ] })
);
```

But after all, when I try to get info, I just can reach profile and email info. Which part of these do I mistake?

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },

    async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
      console.log("profile: ",profile) ...
```

Comment: Have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203108/get-google-people-profile-api-does-not-return-birthday-and-gender-key-values

Answer (score 1):

You can get such data by using the people api as described in the documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing):

1. Activate the People API in the Google API Console [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/people.googleapis.com).

> Fetching data from people API requires a Valid API key
> 2. To create an API key:

1. Navigate to the APIs & Services→Credentials panel in Cloud Console [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials).
2. Select Create credentials, then select API key from the dropdown menu.
3. The API key created dialog box displays your newly created key.
4. Then, perform a simple fetch

> https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/(user_id)?personFields=(fields you want)&key=(valid api key)&access_token=(accessToken in credetials in the result of the authentification)

- Here's how you can get user data: :

  1. add correspondent data to the scope array

  > list of scopes [link](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#profile-scopes)
  > 2. add name of field here `?personFields=(fields you want)`
  > 3. The end user **must** check the box if they want their data to be available to your app
  > [image: allow your app to get that data]

> code i used to get user birthdays

```js
router.get(
        "/login/google",
        passport.authenticate("google")
    );

    // strategy code 

    const getbirthDay = async (id, accessToken) => {

       const response = await fetch(`https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/${id}?personFields=birthdays&key=${process.env.GOOGLE_PEOPLE_API_KEY}&access_token=${accessToken}`);

        data.birthdays.map(entry => {
            const { year, month, day } = entry.date
             console.log(JSON.stringify(entry.date, undefined, 4));
        });

        // const { year, month, day } = data.birthdays[0].date
    }

    passport.use(
        new GoogleStrategy(
            {
                clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
                callbackURL: GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
                passReqToCallback: true,
                scope: ['profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read'],
                state: true
            },

            async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
                const { id } = profile._json
                await getbirthDay(id, accessToken)

            }
        ))
```